# Why is DateTimeOffset +0 > DateTimeOffset +1?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

Why is following statement false?

```
> new DateTimeOffset(2017, 01, 01, 0, 0, 0, 0, TimeSpan.Zero) < new DateTimeOffset(2017, 01, 01, 0, 0, 0, 0, TimeSpan.FromHours(1))

> false
```

Shouldn't be the above statement true since 1 > 0?

Comment: `2017-01-01 00:00:00 +01:00` is *earlier* than `2017-01-01 00:00:00 +00:00`. In other words, time zones do not work that way. Call `.ToUniversalTime()` for more insight: `2017-01-01 00:00:00 +01:00` is `2016-12-31 23:00:00 +00:00`.

Comment: No.  Plus timezones go around earthy towards the east, negative timezones towasrd the west.  So first time is England at noon and second time is France at 1:00.

Comment: DateTimeOffset gives you the offset to a specified timezone, e.g. the difference between that and the current timezone. So if you put in TimeSpan.Hour(1), your offset changes the actuall time by -1 and not +1.

Comment: @Adwaenyth If I print it by adding 1 it says:
> new DateTimeOffset(2017, 01, 01, 0, 0, 0, 0, TimeSpan.FromHours(1))
[01.01.2017 00:00:00 +01:00]

Comment: @Julian Noon at UTC+0 (UK) is earlier than noon at UTC-5 (east coast US).

Comment: @Julian yes, because you're local time (01.01.2017 00:00:00) is already including the +1 hour offset. So in order to get the UTC time, it will deduct 1 hour and get to 31.12.2016 23:00:00 UTC. A.k.a. why new year in Paris is celebrated one hour before London although they are geographically close together.

Comment: Also Fun fact: this offset is also the reason why sunset in Brest today will be at 9:42pm +02:00 (CEST) when it is at 8:28pm +01:00 (BST) in Dover although the sun will set in Dover only 14 minutes before it sets in Brest. (Dover is actually further to the east than Brest).